# prevent scrolling page when focused on contacteditable

Tags: jquery, html

I use [jquery-emojiarea](http://github.com/diy/jquery-emojiarea) on my page and this script creates **contenteditable** div inside the page and when the user still editing this layer and press **space** key the page scrolling down!

I use this

```
$(document).on("keypress", function(e) {
    var $focusElem = $(":focus");
    if(e.which == 32 && ($focusElem.is("input") || $focusElem.attr("contenteditable") == "true")){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

but the page still scrolling down!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my problem was solved. I use nicescroll.js in my project and after removing this file page don't scroll again with space.